# Is there a Tychonoff space $X$ such that ....?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, selection-principles

1. $X$ is not a separable submetrizable, i.e.($iw(X)>\omega$) $X$ has not a countable injective weight.
2. There is a Baire isomorphism 1-class between $X$ and a separable metrizable space $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Now take any uncountable $Q$-set $Y\subset R$ and let $X$ be the one-point compactification of a discrete space of cardinality $|Y|>\omega$.

Comment: Then $X$ and $Y$ is Borel isomorphic (1 - class), but $X$ and $Y$ is not Baire isomorphic ! So the question remains open !